# How to get the 1st value before delimiter in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In one of the column i am getting 2 values with a delimiter between it
How to extract both the values

I have some thing like this Column `TRN02` is `115679-5757`

I need to take values before delimiter and after delimter into 2 separate columns again.

Can some one help me on this

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` to do this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(TRN02, 0, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02)) AS [First],
    SUBSTRING(TRN02, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02)  + 1, LEN(TRN02)) AS [Second]
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: You are missing a comma between the first and the second column.

Answer (score 13):

Just another way USING `LEFT` and `RIGHT` -

```
SELECT LEFT(TRN02, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02) - 1) [before_delim],
       RIGHT(TRN02, LEN(TRN02) - CHARINDEX('-', TRN02)) [after_delim]
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(details, CHARINDEX ('-', TRN02 ) - 1),
       SUBSTRING(details, CHARINDEX ('-', TRN02 ) + 1, 100) 
  FROM Your_table
```

Answer (score -3):

```
update df set df.column=s.[value] FROM table df 
cross APPLY string_split(REPLACE(column, 'split_parameter', '@') ,'@') s  
where column like '%split_parameter%'  and s.[value] not like '=%'
```

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing and why you're doing it.