# Finding a sub string from a string

Tags: sql-server

I have a string like
`"Pros: Cuts WellCons: Not Durable"`
I want to get this sub string
`Pros: Cuts Well`
 A sub string before `Cons`.

Comment: Got any code? Also, tagged "sql-server"? You want to do this in SQL?

Comment: Sop what's not working with your current approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the 1st value before delimiter in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547031/how-to-get-the-1st-value-before-delimiter-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PATINDEX` to get the index of `Cons`. Then use `LEFT` to extract the required substring:

```
SELECT LEFT(@mystring, PATINDEX('%Cons%', @mystring) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to use the word "Cons" as the delimiter, you can use this:

```
declare @string as varchar(100) 
set @string = 'Pros: Cuts WellCons: Not Durable'

select substring(@string,0, patindex('%Cons%', @string))
```

Pat Index finds the first occurrence of the pattern "Cons" in your string. 
Then you just use the substring function using that as the length of the substring.