# How can I parse a comma delimited list in SQL and return the respective columns?

Tags: sql-server, list, delimiter

The following entry almost nails it on the head but not quite: 
[How to get the 1st value before delimiter in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547031/how-to-get-the-1st-value-before-delimiter-in-sql-server)

Have a column that returns the following: 
Fruits
Apple.Orange.Lemon.Grape

Would like to return: 
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHanc.png)

Unfortunately, I'm quite restricted in terms of functions I can use (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077(v=sql.110).aspx). Cannot call on a combo of replace or parsename, and cannot create a function, so how can I use the substring / charindex solution to arrive at the output above?

Comment: Why would you consider calling `parsename()`?  That is a SQL Server function and the question is tagged mysql.

Comment: Could there be unlimited number of fruits?

Comment: Maybe this would help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row

Comment: No only four fruits @Sagi

Comment: @DomB so the table allways contain one row like this: Apple.Orange.Lemon.Grape ?

Comment: That's correct @Sagi

Comment: @DomB posted an answer

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.